# How to prevent a class from being used in another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a class that I want to use only in one thread. If I create an object of the class in one thread and use it in another, it will cause lots of problems. Currently, I resolve this problem like this:
I have Context class and I want to use it only in one thread:

```
public class Context
{
    public Thread CreatedThread { get; }

    public Context()
    {
        CreatedThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
    }

    public void AssertThread()
    {
        if (CreatedThread != Thread.CurrentThread)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Use only one thread!");
        }
    }

    //Lot of properties and methods here
}
```

And here is the usage of Context class in Student class:

```
public class Student
{
    Context context;
    public Context Context
    {
        get
        {
            if (context == null)
                context = new Context();
            context.AssertThread();
            return context;
        }
    }
}
```

And when I use context in a different thread, it will throw an error:

```
var student = new Student();
var context = student.Context;

Task.Run(() =>
{
    var context = student.Context;//InvalidOperationException
});
```

But this solution is not reliable. For example, when I have another class that uses context, I need to do AssertThread on getting context property. Or when I get the context in a new variable and use it in a different thread, my exception will not be thrown. So, is there any solution to enforce class being used only in one thread?

Comment: How about adding `AssertThread()` on the start of every public method and property of the class?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias It might be a solution but not good. It will be messy. Is there any standard way of doing it or maybe someone did the same work

Comment: Check Marc Graville's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20609176/495455

Comment: Perhaps, a Semaphore or SemaphoreSlim could be a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK neither the C# language nor the standard .NET APIs provide a way to embed automatically the `AssertThread()` check in the start of every public method and property of a class. If you don't like the idea of adding this check manually, and you are serious about it, you might want to search for some tool/add-on that can add automatically this check for you at compile time, like the [PostSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postsharp/info), [Fody](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/fody/info) or [alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826724/any-postsharp-alternative).